# One to Many Relationship not showing in the object Amplify Schema definition

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, graphql-js, amplifyjs, graphql-schema

I am new to using amplify with GraphQL. I was setting up my DB schema and auto-generating the functions after running amplify push.

Goals I want to achieve but do not know how to are

1. I would like to be able to get user with all connected information (with one to one and one to many relationships) in the returned object from getUser
2. I would like to still be able to get userByUserName and see all connected one-to-many relationships as well

When calling the API generated function to get the user,

```
let user = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(getUser,{id:userId}))
```

I am getting a user object back, however, it looks like this - even though I am definitely sure that data is set up correctly in the database.

```
buttons: {nextToken: null} -- WANT THIS TO INCLUDE ACTUAL INFORMATION ABOUT BUTTONS CONNECTED TO THIS USER
createdAt: "2020-09-02T23:41:12.278Z"
customStyles: {id: "e3d1bbef-ec6f-4a6d-9b5d-e693e890d4e0", bgColor: "F9FF9F", bgBtnColor: "FFFFFF", bgBtnHoverColor: "000000", textColor: "000000", …}
defaultStyles: null
email: "nata@email.edu"
firstName: "Nata"
id: "d683a6bb-383e-4cf1-943a-05b3da4e5cc3"
lastName: "Vache"
socialNetwork: {nextToken: null} -- WANT THIS TO INCLUDE ACTUAL INFORMATION ABOUT SOCIAL NETWORKS CONNECTED TO THIS USER, THE SAME WAY AS FOR EXAMPLE customStyles IS SHOWN. 
updatedAt: "2020-09-02T23:41:12.278Z"
userName: "Nata568"

type User @model @key(name: "byUserName", fields: ["userName"], queryField: "userByUserName"){
  id: ID!
  firstName: String!
  lastName: String!
  userName: String!
  email: String!
  socialNetwork: [UserSocialNetwork] @connection(keyName: "UserSocialNetworkUser", fields: ["id"])
  buttons: [Button] @connection(keyName: "ButtonUser", fields: ["id"])
  defaultStyles: DefaultStyle @connection
  customStyles: CustomStyle @connection
}

type UserSocialNetwork @model @key(name: "UserSocialNetworkUser", fields: ["userID", "id"], queryField:"userSocialNetworkByUserID") {
  id: ID!
  socialNetworkUsername: String!
  userID: ID!
  supportedSocialNetwork: SupportedSocialNetwork! @connection
}

type SupportedSocialNetwork @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  address: String!
}

type Button @model @key(name: "ButtonUser", fields: ["userID", "id"], queryField: "buttonByUserID") {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  address: String!
  image: String
  userID: ID!
}
```

This schema does not include all my model definitions - customStyles, defaultStyles, and the rest but they are one to one relationship, which is working perfectly fine. I am having issues with one-to-many relationships, such as User to UserSocialNetwork and User to Buttons.

I have read lots of resources about this on AWS Amplify Docs, have gone through examples but still have not found anything that I could work with that would allow me to get the information from connections on getUser call and also give me the ability to get the user by username.
Any input would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Can you accept my answer if that explains the solution for your problem :)

Answer (score 8):

This is a problem with query Depth. It is `2` by default and need to increase it (to `4` in your case).

You can resolve this by following below steps.
In your cmd in your project root, (where you normally run amplify commands).

1. Run `amplify codegen configure` - This will prompt configs again.
2. Enter `4` for this option `Enter maximum statement depth [increase from default if your schema is deeply nested]`
3. Run `amplify codegen` - this will create your queries and mutations according to the new depth.

You can verify it by checking `grapgql/queries.js`.

Earlier you could see below fragment in `getUser` query in `grapgql/queries.js`,

```
buttons {
  nextToken
}
```

But after following above resolution steps, it should be something like below.

```
buttons {
    items {
        id
        image
        address
      }
  }
```

Finally query for your user again.

Comment: but why it's 4?

Answer (score 1):

**General comment:** If username is unique you could use that as the id instead of creating  the extra index. If it isn't there will be problems with this schema since it can't do a getOperation but instead will do a query which might return multiple answers.

(The resolver in Appsync wants to use a `dynamoDB.get` by default (& design) but using an index would be a `dynamoDB.query` which results in a lot issues)

**Anyway** using your schema I can get it to work just fine when using the id

```
  "data": {
    "getUser": {
      "createdAt": "2020-09-07T13:54:23.440Z",
      "email": "meax",
      "firstName": "Max",
      "id": "19a752ec-5050-4e02-8ff8-05d9523e7ea5",
      "socialNetwork": {
        "items": [
          {
            "socialNetworkUsername": "What",
            "id": "280ec8ea-5b25-46d3-8f22-f170e3210146",
            "userID": "19a752ec-5050-4e02-8ff8-05d9523e7ea5"
          }
        ]
      },
      "lastName": "Sc",
      "userName": "zanndo",
      "updatedAt": "2020-09-07T13:54:23.440Z",
      "buttons": {
        "items": [
          {
            "id": "65971568-b388-40a3-b99e-1bff0a730161",
            "image": null,
            "address": "ButonAdre"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This being my query

```
getUser(id: "19a752ec-5050-4e02-8ff8-05d9523e7ea5") {
    createdAt
    email
    firstName
    id
    socialNetwork {
      items {
        socialNetworkUsername
        id
        userID
      }
    }
    lastName
    userName
    updatedAt
    buttons {
      items {
        id
        image
        address
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is one where I made email the id.

```
query MyQuery {
  getUser(id: "sw@gmail.com") {
    id
    firstName
    lastName
    socialNetwork {
      items {
        socialNetworkUsername
        supportedSocialNetwork {
          name
          id
          address
        }
      }
    }
    buttons {
      items {
        id
        address
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also works

```
{
  "data": {
    "getUser": {
      "id": "sw@gmail.com",
      "firstName": "S",
      "lastName": "W",
      "socialNetwork": {
        "items": [
          {
            "socialNetworkUsername": "SomeUserNameOrSomething",
            "supportedSocialNetwork": {
              "name": "Supported1",
              "id": "daf52246-4b25-402c-9fdd-46f8f35e1b89",
              "address": "SupportedAddr"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "buttons": {
        "items": [
          {
            "id": "9883bd91-a2f1-479d-ab65-7a4bbe7b2dc4",
            "address": "ButtonAddr",
            "name": "Button1"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Bonus using your index

```
  userByUserName(userName: "SW") {
    items {
      buttons {
        items {
          name
          id
        }
      }
      socialNetwork {
        items {
          socialNetworkUsername
          supportedSocialNetwork {
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

```
"userByUserName": {
      "items": [
        {
          "buttons": {
            "items": [
              {
                "name": "Button1",
                "id": "9883bd91-a2f1-479d-ab65-7a4bbe7b2dc4"
              }
            ]
          },
          "socialNetwork": {
            "items": [
              {
                "socialNetworkUsername": "SomeUserNameOrSomething",
                "supportedSocialNetwork": {
                  "name": "Supported1"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

This was the schema I used

```
type User @model @key(name: "byUserName", fields: ["userName"], queryField: "userByUserName"){
  firstName: String!
  lastName: String!
  userName: String!
  id: String!
  socialNetwork: [UserSocialNetwork] @connection(keyName: "UserSocialNetworkUser", fields: ["id"])
  buttons: [Button] @connection(keyName: "ButtonUser", fields: ["id"])
}

type UserSocialNetwork @model @key(name: "UserSocialNetworkUser", fields: ["userID", "id"], queryField:"userSocialNetworkByUserID") {
  id: ID!
  socialNetworkUsername: String!
  userID: String!
  supportedSocialNetwork: SupportedSocialNetwork! @connection
}

type SupportedSocialNetwork @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  address: String!
}

type Button @model @key(name: "ButtonUser", fields: ["userID", "id"], queryField: "buttonByUserID") {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  address: String!
  image: String
  userID: String!
}
```

Maybe I have misunderstood something?

Comment: Does your answer suggest that we would need to use custom queries in order to solve this problem? I was more thinking that we could use amplify generated functions getUser and userByUserName. When I look into your schema, I do not see much changes and I was assuming that there was some mistake there originally. The Object data you provided is what I'd like to see on getUser and userByUserName but not sure if you achieved it by creating custom queries.

Comment: Nope I just ran with your schema pretty much or is 'custom queries' referring to the GraphQL Queries? The autogeneration from Amplify is far from perfect (especially with some connections). You might want to check if your DB gives correct answers with my query. If it does you could check that maybe your "depth level" isn't deep enough for Amplify to create correct queries. 
Maybe your autogenerated queries were wrong (happens easily)? Have you checked that?