# Retrieve all connected objects and array of objects in a single query

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm having trouble in bringing nested array of objects from a single query generated by AWS Amplify CLI. I can see I get a single nested object from a single query, but not an array of objects.

I would be highly glad for any of your inputs.

The functionality I want: I have a Model named Post which contains, among others, a list of Comments. I would like to retrieve all posts along with all comments associated with the posts, by not supplying the postId, so esentiially I would like to have a query like getPosts({limit: 50}).

The issue: I don't get the Comments for Posts from the query that I'm issuing. I see a single object, like User, properly returned from the query. In fact, in the query that is generated by Amplify, I see the following query generated for the post model:

```
comments {
         nextToken
       }
```

**I am unable to get a query generated for Post with all the fields from the nested Comment model.**

I followed the discussion at [One to Many Relationship not showing in the object Amplify Schema definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63716173/one-to-many-relationship-not-showing-in-the-object-amplify-schema-definition). But, unfortunately I've not been able to get the result I want.

I went through a few documentations for AWS Amplify, AppSync on the AWS site, but seem unable to fix the issue.

One note - I can see that if I fetch the Comments, I see the parent Post which has this Comment.

I'm sharing the GraphQL schema that I've:

```
type Post
  @model
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, operations: [create, read, update, delete], identityField: "sub" }])
  @key(
    name: "byTime"
    fields: ["type", "createdAt", "updatedAt"]
    queryField: "getPosts"
  )
  @key(
    name: "byUser"
    fields: ["type", "userId"]
    queryField: "getPostsByUser"
  ) {
  type: TableName!
  id: ID!
  userId: String
  user: User! @connection(name: "UserPost")
  createdAt: AWSDateTime!
  updatedAt: AWSDateTime!
  title: String
  content: String
  files: [S3Object]
  comments: [Comment!]
    @connection(
      keyName: "byPostId"
      fields: ["id", "updatedAt"]
      name: "PostComments"
    )
  likes: [User]
  likeCount: String
}

type Comment
  @model
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, operations: [create, read, update, delete], identityField: "sub" }])
  @key(
    name: "byTime"
    fields: ["type", "createdAt", "updatedAt"]
    queryField: "getComments"
  )
  @key(
    name: "byPostId"
    fields: ["postId", "updatedAt"]
    queryField: "getCommentsByPostId"
  ){
  type: TableName!
  id: ID!
  postId: ID!
  userId: String
  content: String
  createdAt: AWSDateTime!
  updatedAt: AWSDateTime!
  post: Post @connection(fields: ["postId"])
  likes: [User]
  likeCount: String
  user: User @connection
}

enum TableName {
  User
  Profile
  Post
  Comment
}

type User
  @model
  @key(
    name: "byUserEmail"
    fields: ["type", "email"]
    queryField: "getUserByEmail"
  )
  
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: owner, operations: [read, create, delete, update], identityField: "sub" }
    ]
  ) {
  id: ID!
  type: TableName!
  name: String!
  email: ID!
  createdAt: String
  profile: Profile @connection(name: "UserProfile")
  profileCreated: Boolean
  posts: [Post] @connection(name: "UserPost")
}

type Profile
  @model
  @key(
    name: "byUserId"
    fields: ["type", "userId"]
    queryField: "getProfileByUserId"
  )
  @key(
    name: "byUserEmail"
    fields: ["type", "userEmail"]
    queryField: "getProfileByUserEmail"
  )
   @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: owner, operations: [create, read, update, delete], identityField: "sub" }
    ]
  ) {
  id: ID!
  type: TableName!
  userId: ID!
  role: Role!
  classRoom: String
  ... other fields
  user: User @connection(name: "UserProfile")
}

enum Role {
  TeachingStaff
  Student
  NonTeachingStaff
  Alumni
}

type S3Object {
  bucket: String! 
  region: String! 
  key: String! 
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The issue could be fixed by:

1. updating Amplify CLI to the latest version
2. incresing the query depth
3. modifying the schema a bit